# Less compile and subfolder components

Tags: css, phpstorm, less, webstorm

I have folder structure like this.

Folder with components:

```
/template/less/components/*.less
```

Folder with modules:

```
/template/less/*.less
```

This is one content example of module file:

```
@import '/components/component1.less';
@import '/components/component2.less';
@import '/components/component3.less';
```

I used this command to generate module like this:

```
lessc module1.less module1.css --autoprefix="last 3 versions"
```

It generate module1.css. Its OK.

Problem is that it also generate all components to *.css files and I don't want it.

How to tell the compiler not to generate css files from the components folder?

Same problem is that PhpStorm 2023.1 file watcher doing the same.

My lessc is v4.1.3 installed over npm.

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest submitting this query to https://github.com/less/less.js/issues

Comment: It was OK and problem started few days ago after npm update or any different environment change. Less compiler is without version change last 1 year.